# Angular CLI wont create new project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a project (named ngadmin) via the angular cli but it throws errors on this command: `ng new ngadmin`. The errors are:

> fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are
>   using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent
>   version.
>
> You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project.

I am not sure what the problem is as this cli was working fine for me a few days ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check in your ***username*** folder, if there is `package.json` and `node_module` exist. If they are there then delete them.

Notice:  you may have created an angular project in your `home/username` directory. If you delete them it will work.

Answer (score 7):

If using Linux, go to home and delete `package.json`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. Here is how I fixed it:

- Go to package.json
- Under "Dependencies", find "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.18"
- Delete this line ("angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.18")
- Save file

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

The first warning regarding graceful-fs is due to the fact that angular-cli uses older version of graceful-fs pkg, nothing to worry about that.

The error **"You cannot use the new command inside an angular-cli project"** signifies you are inside an angular cli project, get out of the angular cli project using `cd ..` command and try running the command `ng new ngadmin` it will work.

Comment: Hey, yup i had tried that, i tried to create the project in multiple locations on my pc including right on the c drive. always got the same error

Answer (score 1):

there is a file **package.json**

Simply remove it and then Create project. 
it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i fixed my problem. I have no idea what happened but i noticed system32 was not in my PATH so i added that and uninstalled and reinstalled the angular-cli package. everything works like a charm now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the thing was I was not closely following along the tutorial I was watching and I tried using the same directory, I used **cd ..** to move up in the file structure and it worked like a charm, hope this helps! 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem today, I started a fresh project and did

```
 npm install -save @angular/cli
```

and received the error.
I just renamed the package.json to .json2 temporarily and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file `package.json` in current directory where you are trying to create. Then try to install again.

Answer (score 0):

In windows cd/User,Find the package.json,package-lock.json file and delete both the files.

Restart your command prompt and you are ready to go.And try to use this command

npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score -1):

You must have used local "npm install @angular/cli" command to install angular locally in your project.

Uninstall local angular using "npm uninstall @angular/cli"
install angular globally using "npm install -g @angular/cli"

and then try "ng new ngadmin"

Because "ng new projectName" will automatically install angular/cli locally as a dev-dependency